# How to use default system map in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building an app that has a map. However, in a different region, there are different map services providers. I want to know is there a way to use the default system map in flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library provide a method that you can use/show native map based on the platform, for ios, apple map is used, for android, google map is used, [platform_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/platform_maps_flutter)